# Magento 2 Header Sign In Sign Out Issue on Home Page

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, block-cache

I'm facing an issue on Magento 2.2 . The details are as under

1.Go to home page

2.Click 'Sign In' from header

3.Enter login credentials to enter customer account

4.Click website logo to go back to home page

5.Notice that on the home page the header is still showing 'Sign In' instead of showing the customer is logged in and a 'Sign Out' link.

can anybody help me out

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I am facing this issue on 2.3.3. I have both redis and varnish.

Comment: @Aqib What is the solution for this? Even i am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your browser console log. Magento reloads this information with Javascripts. Console can show some hints for fixing this issue. Also this issue can be related to updating customer section data.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as you are. It was a conflict with varnish cache.

But after I removed var and pub/static directory except .htaccess file my issue
 was solved.

As per my suggestion you can try to remove var and pub/static except .htaccess file.

**Magento root directory run below commands:**

- **rm -rf var/* pub/static/***
- **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
- **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
- **php bin/magento cache:flush**

Let me know if any issue.

Hope it help!

Answer (score -1):

It is only the caching issue, flush cache Storage, flush Javascript cache, flush Magento cache and Refresh All type of cache from admin.Then remove browser cache and check. It works.

Comment: so we are supposed to flush cache every time after after sign in/sign out?